# Pass a boolean to all tabs in a UITabController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

In my app, there is `UITabBarController` that has 3 TabBar. `TabBarController` is called from `ViewController` that has a boolean variable in it.

I want to pass this value from `UIViewController` to `UITabBarController` (in `-prepareForSegue`, I assume) so that I can get this value in all the tabs of `TabBarController`.

How can I pass this variable and how can I access the from each TabBar?

Comment: You can store that value in `NSUserDefault` and access that value from other classes.

Comment: do not go for NSUserDefault - that's wrong pattern :( of course it works but there are so better ways of doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of solving it will be to use delegates.
You can extend `UITabBarController` with your own class and create a delegate methods to communicate with UIViewController.
Than in prepareForSegue method you can get boolean on demand using this method.

If you never used it before, here is a nice read about Protocol and delegation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

Another idea will be to again extend `UITabBarController` and add BOOL property to it and update it every single time from `UIViewController`. The best way will be to create custom setter in your `UIViewController` that updates according property in `UITabBarController`.
In this case you can just use `self.boolproperty` in UITabBar segue.

But if you want to do it in Obj-C style - delegate is the way to go.

Comment: inheriting from `UITablBarController` and storing the boolean in the subclass's instance is indeed the way to go

Comment: I tried to do this, if I am understanding you rightly. I made a class for UITabBarController and declared a BOOL inside it, inherited it in my first ViewController and set the value from that during -prepareForSegue. This way, I got the variable inside the UITabBarController. How do I acces this from individual Tabs?

Comment: Why you want to access them from UITabBar right away ? I don't see when it could be needed ? You can do the same and extend UITabBar class and propagate value or delegate

Comment: its an app that has 2 languages. I can select a language from the viewcontroller and the display in all the tabs of the Tabcontroller must change

Comment: For that it's better to use build in localization in iOS and you can then change preferred language and reload the views.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski Hello, there. sorry for the late reply. I am too deep in my app right now and I didn't know about Localization before. I have text for every place holders and button titles in both English and Arabic (those are my 2 languages). My plan is to set the language in the first page. this page takes to the tabcontroller that has 3 tabs and do a check in all the tabs at ViewDidLoad and refresh the contents using a method. what do you think?

Comment: I would recommend reloading the whole application after language has changed - that's probably easiest.

Answer (score 1):

You should subclass the UITabbarController and create property and synthesize it, after that you can access the property on respective controller.

```
 
  @interface CustomTabController : UITabBarController

  @property(nonatomic,assign) BOOL isSelect;

  @end
```

```
  @implementation CustomTabController

  @synthesize isSelect;

  @end
```

Once you done this, Go to story board and select your tabbarcontroller and set tabbarcontroller Custom class to 'CustomTabController'

After setting you just need to include "CustomTabController.h" file in your desire viewcontroller and just create an object of tabbarcontroller and access the property, property is getter and setter so you can also set the property 
see in below image.

```
    //import your 'CustomTabController.h'  and write below code where ever you want to get tabbar property.



      CustomTabController *controller = (CustomTabController *)self.tabBarController;

      BOOL selected = controller.isSelect;  //Gettting current value of isSelect
      controller.isSelect = NO; //Setting value for isSelect
```

Comment: I tried this method and got the variable into my TabController. but how do I access this variable from individua tabs?

Comment: You can just import TabContorller in your tab and write below code <br/>       CustomTabController *controller = (CustomTabController *)self.tabBarController;    you can get your property in controller object